# Update field in firestore document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code:

```
function saveID(sender_psid,complete){
   let data = new Object();
   data.TASK= complete;
   data.ID = sender_psid;
   db.collection('users').add(data);
}
```

Right now a new document is created every time the field complete is updated. I want to update the value of complete in firestore instead of creating a new document each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to update an existing document, build a [DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/DocumentReference) that points to the document to update, and use its [update()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/DocumentReference#update) method to indicate which fields should be changed.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) goes over this and gives a code sample:

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Set the 'capital' field of the city
var updateSingle = cityRef.update({ capital: true });
```